# Flutter - Exception: FlutterApplicationInfo.flutterAssetsDir' on a null object reference on Videocontroller/Chewie init with video from assets

Tags: flutter

we currently facing an exception which is thrown after we init our videoController like so:

```
_videoController =
        VideoPlayerController.asset('lib/resources/media/video.mp4');
_chewieController = ChewieController(
  allowFullScreen: true,
  autoInitialize: true,
  videoPlayerController: _videoController,
  showControls: true,
  autoPlay: false,
  looping: false,
);
```

The full exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterApplicationInfo.flutterAssetsDir' on a null object reference
```

With stacktrace:

[image: stacktrace]

Our **Application**:

```
public class Application extends FlutterApplication  implements PluginRegistrantCallback  {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name=".Application"
```

Is there something wrong with our `Application` implementation?

**flutter doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale en-GB)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale en-GB)
```

Comment: Facing a similar issue with Flutter v1.22.3 with firebase messaging with 8.0.0-dev.5